# What if distribution profile or distribution certificates expires after app is avalialbe in app store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have published my app first time this year on app store. Now I have received email that Distribution Profile and Distribution Certificate which I used for app publication are about to expires. So my query is whether it will affect my current published app if I will not revoke both certificate and profile.

Let's say my profile and certificate get expired and some user tries to download my app from app store then will it work?

Comment: Once it leaves your computer and goes into itunes connect, you don't have to care about certs anymore until the next time you want to make an update.

Answer (score 1):

**Nothing happens.**

Previous submitted apps will be working fine. No need to worry about it. Because there is no link between a distribution's certification status and use of apps by customers. But if you want to submit new version of app or new app in appstore you have to revoke it.

You can get more info from [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/certificates/).

> iOS Distribution Certificate (App Store):
>
> If your iOS Developer Program membership is valid, your existing apps on the App Store will not be affected. However, you will no longer be able to submit new apps or updates to the App Store.

Comment: Just for clarification I am not concerned about Development certificates and profiles. I am worried about Distribution Profile and Distribution Certificate (Production Certificate) which are used earlier for publishing app on app store. I hope you are talking about that. Because you mentioned "Dev's certification" so I just wanted to clear my point on this

Comment: ya i am taking about Distribution Profile and Distribution Certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no need to worry about Distribution Profile and Distribution Certificate (Production Certificate) which are used earlier for publishing app on app store. You just need to generate new certificate when you want to upload new version of application.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.